# installing ubuntu with windows installer

Tags: dual-boot, windows

if I use this method to install ubuntu on my windows 7, will I lose windows 7 or will it dual boot with windows and ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It will dual boot. It installs Ubuntu to  folder on your C: drive. If, for any reason, you eve want to remove Ubuntu from Windows you just have to go to Windows Control Panel > Program > uninstall a program and remove it.